# Чи правильно вживати слово «самородок»?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, росіянізм

Іноді у публікаціях ЗМІ та на телебаченні зустрічається слово «самородок» у значенні талановитої людини, яка професійно не займалась розвитком своїх здібностей.

Зокрема, у такому контексті на [Україна Live](http://ukraine-live.com/news/33253):

> «Справжній самородок … розвернув всі суддівські крісла і зipвав бурю аплодисментів».

Схоже застосування міститься на [каналі 24](//24tv.ua/golos_krayini_2018_3_vipusk_8_sezon_divitisya_online_11_02_2018_n923904).

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/samorodok) містить визначення даного поняття:

> 2. *перен.* Людина, у якої природний хист, нахил до чого-небудь виявилися без впливу освіти й виховання.

Та попри присутність такого слова у словниках, воно не є активним у вжитку. Доказом цього є те, що пошукові системи видають посилання на сайти, де *самородок* — це частинка або уламок самородного металу, здебільшого благородного, що різко виділяється за розмірами серед інших частинок природного металу.

Аналогічне [основне] значення слова міститься в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/samorodok)  та у [Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Доволі мала кількість прикладів вживання свідчить про те, що це слово не надто активно використовується.

Більше того, воно співзвучне з російським «самородок», що позначає особу, наділену талантом, який проявився сам. Складається із двох слів «сам родился». Як на мене, то звучить як калька з російської.

*У звʼязку з цим питання: чи можна в українській мові вживати слово «самородок»?*

Comment: Зазначу: 1) українська мова теж має: слова _сам_ і _родити_ (_рід_), наростка [_-ок_](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky "64. б) при творенні нових іменників різноманітного змісту"); 2) про всяк треʼ обачніше вибирати приклади ӝерел, бо коли існує паралельно московська, є велика ймовірність [машиноперекладу](//zbruc.eu/node/76615 "«Шляхи повідомлення»
Юрій Андрухович") саме з неї.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Як ви зазначили, це слово є в СУМі, а також коло нього немає позначки, що воно рідко вживається, тому це вже створює основу для припущення, що його правильно вживати в укрїнській мові. В [Етимологічному словнику](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2006/EtSlUkrM_2006.pdf) (ст. 174) хоч і немає "самородка", однак є "саморідник" утворене від слів "сам" і "родити", однак, варто зазначити, що слово "самородок" також" не перечить правила українського словотвору.

Крім того, це слово досить часто вживається і сьогодні, ось декілька прикладів, які мені з легкістю вдалося знайти ([1](http://www.visti.rovno.ua/article/samorodok-iz-berejnici/),[2](http://7d.rv.ua/iplus/2018-06-21/muzykant-samorodok-z-rivnogo-peremig-u-teleshou-karaoke-na-maydani),[3](https://decentralization.gov.ua/en/news/6861?page=2),[4](http://ukraine-live.com/news/33253),[5](https://24tv.ua/golos_krayini_2018_3_vipusk_8_sezon_divitisya_online_11_02_2018_n923904)), що свідчить, що про переносне значення слова "самородок" ще ніхто не забув.